# AWS Rekognition and s3 calling subfolders in Python Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access a certain folder within a bucket in s3 using Python

Let's say I'm trying to access this folder in the bucket which contains a bunch of images that I want to run rekognition on:
"myBucket/subfolder/images/"

In /images/ folder there are:

```
one.jpg  
two.jpg  
three.jpg  
four.jpg
```

I want to run rekognition's detect_labels on this folder. However, I can't seem to access this folder but if I change the bucket_name to just the root folder ("myBucket"/), then I can access just that folder.

```
bucket_name = "myBucket/subfolder/images/"  
rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')  
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')  
bucket = s3.Bucket(name=bucket_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is operating as expected. The bucket name should be **just the name of the bucket**.

You can then run operation on the bucket, eg:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')

for object in bucket.objects.all():
    if object.key.startswith('images'):
        print object.key
```

Or, using the `client` instead of the `resource`:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket', Prefix='images/')

for object in response['Contents']:
    print object['Key']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could index elsewhere what you have in S3, in such a way, you directly access what you need. Have in mind that to loop against files stored in buckets, may offer very low performance and it gets really slow if the number of keys you have is big.

Following your example, another way to do it:

```
bucket_name = "myBucket"  
folder_name = "subfolder/images/"  
rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')

keys= ['one.jpg','two.jpg','three.jpg','four.jpg']
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')  
for k in keys:
  obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, folder_name+k )
  print(obj.key)
```

Get the list of items(`keys`) from any db table in your system.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of AWS Rekognition (as asked), an image file stored in a folder in a S3 bucket will have the key in the form of `folder_name/subfolder_name/image_name.jpg`.  So, since the boto3 Rekognition `detect_labels()` method has this syntax (per https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.detect_labels):

```
response = client.detect_labels(
    Image={
        'Bytes': b'bytes',
        'S3Object': {
            'Bucket': 'string',
            'Name': 'string',
            'Version': 'string'
        }
    },
    MaxLabels=123,
    MinConfidence=...
)
```

where the value of `Name` should be a S3 object key name, you can just feed the entire folder-image path to that dictionary as a string. To loop over multiple images, generate a list of image file names, as recommended in Evhz's answer, and loop over that list while calling the `detect_labels()` method above (or use a generator).

Comment: Just a clarification, "you **CAN'T** just feed the entire folder-image path to that dictionary as a string", right?

Comment: @TulioCasagrande you **CAN**.  It would be: 'Name': 'folder_name/subfolder_name/image_name.jpg' . That path is the key S3 assigns to each image.

Comment: Oh, right! I interpreted that wrong. Thanks @AlexK!